# How can I get rid of a Blender element I cannot select?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

In object mode there is a blender element attached to a particular object which appears to be a vertex, though I'm working in a large scale, so it could be a small edge or face. I don't want it there, but I cannot seem to select the item in object mode, and it disappears in edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard to find or select object can often be deleted from the outliner.

Here I have a cube that has all of it's vertices deleted but is still a child of another cube. In the outliner I can expand the parent to see the child, by right clicking on Cube.001 I can then select delete.

[image]

Comment: Sampler, a hard to find or select object can only be deleted from the outliner if one knows to look there. It was the appearance of the modifier icon in the outliner that alerted me to the existence of the modifier, but because I managed to apply the modifier without intending to, or knowing that I did, I didn't think to look for it in the outliner window, and with the trees for all of the various objects collapsed, it wasn't immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you may have added a modifier to your object. Some modifiers, for example, the hook modifier, add empties that are used in the function of the modifier that show in object mode, but which cannot be selected in edit mode.

Comment: That is what should appear when you use the hook modifier. You can't select empties in edit mode either way.

Comment: Well, I know that now, but I spent a couple of weeks wondering why I had what appeared in edit mode to be a vertex. My idea here is to try to spare some one else the two weeks of wondering.